# function access variable declared in decorator

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-decorators

I want to log a lot of metrics such as how long it took for a function to execute. I'd like the solution to be lightweight. Add a decorator and be done. Maybe 90% of the time like this:

```
@LogMetrics
def my_business_logic(var1):
  print 'done'
```

However, I'd also like to be able to access the metrics object and do something like this 10% of the time:

```
@LogMetrics
def my_business_logic(var1):
  metrics.inc_counter('counter_a')
  print 'done'
```

So far I have a decorator that handles the first scenario:

```
class LogMetrics(object):

  def __init__(self, module=None):
    self.module = module


  def __call__(self, target):

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
      # set up metrics
      metrics = Metrics(module=module)

      metrics.start_timer()
      try:
        result = target(*args, **kwargs)
      except Exception as e:
        metrics.set_fault()
        raise e
      finally:
        metrics.stop_timer()
        metrics.push()

      return result

    return wrapped
```

How do I support scenario 2? I wanted to do something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/592019/654495), but the consensus seems to be not to do it. Please help...

Comment: Magically messing with `globals()` is indeed a very bad idea, don't do that. If you must, just create an old-fashioned singleton.

Comment: How does a singleton help when I need to use this metrics object everywhere?

Comment: You could add some global/static dictionary, which will store {qualname: Metric} dictionary for all functions and methods you want to decorate. Then in LogMetric.__call__ you could fetch appropriate Metric for the wrapped function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that doesn't involve global objects or forbidden magic is to pass your metrics object as an optional argument to your function (I'm assuming that if you can edit it, then you can change its signature):

```
class LogMetrics(object):

  ...

  def __call__(self, target):

    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
      # set up metrics
      metrics = Metrics(module=module)
      kwargs['metrics'] = metrics  # add metrics object to kwargs
      metrics.start_timer()
      try:
        result = target(*args, **kwargs)
      except Exception as e:
        metrics.set_fault()
        raise e
      finally:
        metrics.stop_timer()
        metrics.push()
      return result
    return wrapped


@LogMetrics
def my_business_logic(var1, metrics=None):
  if metrics is not None:
      metrics.inc_counter('counter_a')
  print 'done'
```

By the way, are you sure you want to initialize `Metrics` inside `wrapped` and not inside `__call__`?

Comment: Regarding the extra param: I feared that was the case. I don't follow your question about LogMetrics. LogMetrics isn't initialized in wrapped..

Comment: Regarding the extra param: that means the signature of the method shows a metrics input. I guess that means the method needs to be namespaced.. i.e. a public version of the method has no metrics arg, but it calls a private version of the method which takes the metrics arg.

Comment: My mistake: I meant `Metric`, not `LogMetric`. Regarding private function with metric param: yes, it's probably the cleanest way.

Comment: Hmm.. I wouldn't always need the metric param. I guess I need to only add it to kwargs when the function signature has a metrics arg in there

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute to a function. I made a very simple example (in Python3). The `add_counter` decorator adds a `_counter` attribute to the original function (you will add a `metrics` object instead). The counter in this example is incremented after each call. Finally an `_orig_func` attribute is added to the decorated function to allow access to the counter.

```
def add_counter(func):
    func._counter = 0 
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        func._counter += 1
        return result
    decorated._orig_func = func
    return decorated

@add_counter
def func1():
    print("FUNC1")
    print(func1._orig_func._counter)

@add_counter
def func2():
    print("FUNC2")
    print(func2._orig_func._counter)

func1()
func1()
func1()
func2()
func2()
func1()
```